# How to show full screen grid with dataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am reading an XML database and storing the entries in dataSet. 
For UI, I am using dataGridView. So, all my database entries will be shown in dataGridView. Currently, if there are two entries in database, the grid is shown for two entries and all the other rows are shown blank.
I want to show full screen grid with dataGridView. If I have two entries in database, I sholuld see two entries and all other rows/columns with empty cells but with grid. No part of datagridView should be blank. Please help for solving the problem.
I tried using properties such as Dock, AutoSizeColumnsMode, AutoSizeRowsMode etc of dataGridView but was not able to achieve this.

Here's the code for reading data.

```
private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridView1;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dtAll = new DataTable();
XmlReader xmlFile; 
xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("Filepath");
ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);
dtTable = ds.Tables[0].Copy();
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["entry"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a from, where you place your grid.
The Form should have no border and maximized.
This will show up your form full screen.

```
this.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

Answer (score 0):

You check how many rows that grids shows at once,
For example if it supports 20 rows to show with out scrolling and you have only 5 rows, then you have to add 15 empty rows to the table ds.Tables["entry"].

Answer (score 0):

Going off the suggestion by [Manoj Extreme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31714905/3773066), you can fill the sourced `DataTable` with dummy rows to fill the height of the `DataGridView`. For the width, just set `AutoSizeColumnsMode` to `Fill`, or more specifically, only set `AutoSizeMode` for the column containing the largest data. For example:

```
DataTable dt = ds.Tables["entry"];

while (dt.Rows.Count * dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height + dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight < dataGridView1.Height)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(string.Empty);
}

dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
dataGridView1.Columns["TheBigDataColumnName"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
```

Note: There is a downside to this method. If you allow the user to change the row's heights, grow the Form's height, or delete rows then you will have to do something similar afterwards to fix the resulting non-filled space.